# vb noughts and crosses issue

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I've been teaching myself to code by doing different projects, the most recent one being noughts and crosses. The program works I but need help with two things. The full code is at the end.

1. how do you add the option of letting the user play again?
   I tried the code below but it keeps asking the user the question twice.
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHQgR.png)

   ```
   Sub playagain()
       If winner = True Then
           Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do now?")
           Console.WriteLine("1. Play again")
           Console.WriteLine("2. Leave")
           choice = Console.ReadLine()

           Select Case choice
               Case "1"
                   Main()

               Case "2"
                   Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!")
                   Console.ReadLine()
           End Select

       End If
   End Sub
   ```
2. How do i add a function to tell the user that the position they have picked is already taken? i tried the code below but can't get it to work.

```
Sub checkvalidmove()
        If board(position) = marker Then
            Console.WriteLine("position taken")
            Console.ReadLine()
```

full code

```
Dim position As Integer
   Dim board(8) As String
    Dim marker As String = "X"
    Dim winner As Boolean = False
    Dim choice As String


    Sub setup()
        For j = 0 To 8
            board(j) = j
        Next j
    End Sub
    Sub showboard()
        'set board
        'board will be 3x3 and will be numbered 0 to 8
        Console.WriteLine(board(0) & "|" & board(1) & "|" & board(2))
        Console.WriteLine("-------------")
        Console.WriteLine(board(3) & "|" & board(4) & "|" & board(5))
        Console.WriteLine("-------------")
        Console.WriteLine(board(6) & "|" & board(7) & "|" & board(8))
    End Sub
    Sub Main()

        'tells player 1 is X and player 2 is O
        Console.WriteLine("Players are represented with a character")
        Console.WriteLine(" Player 1 = X.  Player 2 = O")

        setup()
        showboard()
        Do
            Do
                'ask player to pick a number
                Console.WriteLine("player pick a number")
                position = Console.ReadLine
            Loop Until board(position) <> "X" Or board(position) <> "O"
            board(position) = marker
            showboard()
            check()
            playagain()

            If marker = "X" Then
                marker = "O"
            Else
                marker = "X"
            End If
        Loop Until winner


    End Sub
    Sub check()

        'winning conditions for horizontal
        If board(0) = board(1) And board(0) = board(2) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
        If board(3) = board(4) And board(3) = board(5) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
        If board(6) = board(7) And board(6) = board(8) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
        'winning condition for vertical
        If board(0) = board(3) And board(0) = board(6) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
        If board(1) = board(4) And board(1) = board(7) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
        If board(2) = board(5) And board(2) = board(8) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
        'winning condition for diagonal
        If board(0) = board(4) And board(0) = board(8) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            Console.ReadLine()
        End If
        If board(2) = board(4) And board(2) = board(6) Then
            Console.WriteLine("winner")
            winner = True
            winner = Console.ReadLine()
        End If

    End Sub
    Sub playagain()
        If winner = True Then
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do now?")
            Console.WriteLine("1. Play again")
            Console.WriteLine("2. Leave")
            choice = Console.ReadLine()

            Select Case choice
                Case "1"
                    Main()

                Case "2"
                    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!")
                    Console.ReadLine()
            End Select

        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Your `playagain` function creates a recursion; after a certain number of re-plays, it will fail with a stack overflow (admittedly, the number of plays might be large enough that it wouldn't be hit in practice).  It would be better to have an additional condition on the main loop rather than recursing into main from `playagain`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It worked for me!
2. Change checkvalidmove() to a function.  For example

   ```
    Function ValidMove() As Boolean
        If board(position) = marker Then
            Console.WriteLine("position taken")
            Console.ReadLine()
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If
    End Function
   ```

then change the condition on the inner do loop to

```
Loop Until ValidMove
```

3. As a bonus comment, use Console.ReadKey instead of Console.ReadLine so that the user does not have to press Enter after each entry; such as :

   ```
    dim cki as ConsoleKeyInfo
    cki = Console.ReadKey
   ```

then use cki.Key to see which key was pressed.

Have fun

Comment: I did what you suggested and the second part works however I cant't get the first part to work. Also, do you know how to do a check when the game ends in a draw?

Comment: @M98  Which part doesn't work; please be more specific: What does "can't get the first part to work" mean?  There are a few ways to recognize a draw such as keeping track of the number of times a cell  has been filled - if that number reaches nine without a win having been declared, then, by definition, that is a draw.

Comment: @ SezMe when it gives the options to play again or quit, when you choose to play again after the first move it will keep repeating the options. Here is an image of the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHQgR.png.  How do I get the program to keep track of the number of turns?

Comment: @M98 You have to reset "winner",  So Case 1 includes winner = False before you call Main() again

Comment: To keep track of turns create a new variable: Dim Turns as integer.  Then, just before your outer loop set it to zero.  Immediately after the "Do" of the outer loop increment it with Turns += 1.